# How do I return an array by passing a string as reference to the array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have array lists of cities defined by state abbreviations.

```
static List<String> AL = Arrays.asList("ABBEVILLE","ADAMSVILLE",.....
static List<String> AK = Arrays.asList("ADAK","AKHIOK",......
```

The same thing happens to the array no matter which one is called. How do I pass a string of 'AL' and access the array list AL? I currently use a case statement... But its a lot of code for all 50 and I want to trim it down a bit..

```
 case "AL":
   for(int index = 0; index < AL.size(); index++){.....}
 case "AK":
   for(int index = 0; index < AK.size(); index++){.....}
```

Id rather something like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < state_abbreviation.size(){
  System.out.println(state_abbreviation[index]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could store every `List<String>` in a `Map` and use the state abbreviation as the map's key.

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> states = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> al = Arrays.asList("ABBEVILLE", "ADAMSVILLE", "...");
        List<String> ak = Arrays.asList("ADAK", "AKHIOK", "...");
        states.put("AL", al);
        states.put("AK", ak);
        System.out.println(states.get("AL").get(1)); // ADAMSVILLE
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not really cut down on the amount of code and misses my for loops.